# Force Download mp3 file from wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying to download a file from my custom post. I use the pods plugin for creating the post and the post templates.

the code i use is `<a href="{@audio_file._src}">Download</a>`

This code only plays the audio file. 
what can I do to create a simple downloading link?

Answer (score 2):

I found out 
add `download="true"` inside the anchor as an attribute and that should force download instead of playback
Got it working with only download inside the anchor
Ex `<a href="{@audio_file._src}" download="true" >Download</a>`

Hope this will help other noobs like me :)

Comment: <a href="{@audio_file._src}" download="true" >Download</a> wil downloade it width file name tru.mp3. So if you use <a href="{@audio_file._src}" download  >Download</a>  then it will force download width right name